# MySQL showing zero results when there be some?

Tags: mysql

I have a table as per below:

```
id | description | db_url | form_url | user | projectid

2 | nailbar | TSF/nailbar/index.php | TSF/nailbar/upload.php | test_user | 2

1 | jewellery | TSF/jewellery/index.php | TSF/jewellery/upload.php | test_user | 1

1 | jewellery | TSF/jewellery/index.php | TSF/jewellery/upload.php | test_user2 | 1

3 | locker | TSF/locker/index.php | TSF/locker/upload.php | test_user | 3
```

When I execute the below query nothing comes up:

```
SELECT * 
FROM projects
JOIN member_projects ON member_projects.projectid = projects.id
WHERE user =  'test_user'
AND db_url =  'TSF/locker/index.php'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

There clearly is a match so I can't understand why it is coming up with zero results?

Comment: is your table the projects or member_projects table? and is data in the other one?

Comment: Limit 0... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limit-optimization.html  states, "LIMIT 0 quickly returns an empty set."  or it could be the The join is eliminating the data. Though I'm not sure if the ,30 overrides the limit 0. Also does ID 3 exist in both projects and member_projects tables?  if not the join could be removing records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would typically happen when there are extra characters on the beginning or end of the strings.  The most likely culprit is the url.  You can try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM projects p JOIN
     member_projects mp
     ON mp.projectid = p.id
WHERE user =  'test_user' AND
      trim(db_url) =  'TSF/locker/index.php'
LIMIT 0 , 30;
```

You can also look for "contains" rather than full matches, if the above doesn't work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM projects p JOIN
     member_projects mp
     ON mp.projectid = p.id
WHERE user =  'test_user' AND
      db_url like '%TSF/locker/index.php%'
LIMIT 0 , 30;
```

Comment: Jackpot! the second one worked, thank you so much! I'll accept the answer as soon as I can.